# VerifierMappingExceptions with Spring Boot 1.3.1 when using Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring-boot-starter-parent letting Spring manage all dependencies for my project, and with that i am using Spring Data Cassandra and Spring data JPA

The version of Spring-boot-starter-parent was 1.2.8.RELEASE.Lately I updated the version to 1.3.1.RELEASE and starting to face a weird issue with Spring Data Cassandra

```
 21:23:21.783 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   - Failed to check for ThreadLocal references for web application [ROOT]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.FastList.iterator(FastList.java:209) ~[HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadedByThisOrChild(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2195) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2105) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalsForLeaks(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2060) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1575) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.stop(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:447) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
21:23:21.791 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication         - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sarvint.service.intf.UserService com.sarvint.rest.UserController.uService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sarvint.repositories.UserRepository com.sarvint.service.UserServiceImpl.userRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: com.sarvint.domain.User:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sarvint.Application.main(Application.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sarvint.service.intf.UserService com.sarvint.rest.UserController.uService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sarvint.repositories.UserRepository com.sarvint.service.UserServiceImpl.userRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: com.sarvint.domain.User:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sarvint.repositories.UserRepository com.sarvint.service.UserServiceImpl.userRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: com.sarvint.domain.User:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation
```

It says I have to annotate Entities with @Table etc , but those entities are of Spring data JPA
Entities which are of Spring data Cassandra i have annotated with @Table etc

Start-class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories( repositoryFactoryBeanClass =    GenericRepositoryFactoryBean.class )
@EntityScan("com.sarvint.domain")
@Import(CassandraConfig.class)
public class Application {

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

}

Spring Data JPA config :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.sarvint" )
@PropertySource( value = { "classpath:application.properties" } )
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            @Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling( DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer )
{
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()
{
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    int poolSize = 20;
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);
    config.setDataSourceClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("url", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

Spring Data JPA entity :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "user" )

public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
@Column( name = "u_id" )
private Integer userId;

@Column( name = "u_first_name" )
private String firstName;

@Column( name = "u_last_name" )
private String lastName;
}
```

Now coming to Spring Data Cassandra config :

```
    package com.sarvint.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages="com.sarvint.cassandra.domain")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);


    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        LOG.info("INSIDE cluster()");
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
        return cluster;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        LOG.info("INSIDE getting keyspace name");
        return environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace");
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LOG.info("INSIDE cassandra mapping");
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }
}
```

Spring Cassandra entity :

```
import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

@Table( value = "biometric_param" )
public class BiometricParam {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="user_id",ordinal=0,type=PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private Integer userId;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="workout_uuid",ordinal=1,type=PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String workoutUUID;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="bio_param_key",ordinal=2,type=PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String bioParamKey;

    @Column(value="bio_param_val")
    private Float bioParamValue;
}
```

Cassandra.properties

```
cassandra.contactpoints=127.0.0.1
cassandra.port=9042
cassandra.keyspace=test
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2):

### What's the issue?

This is a bug in Spring Data Cassandra. You have multiple Spring Data modules on your class-path. In such a case Spring Data tries to figure out to which module a particular Repository belongs. Spring Data Cassandra misses the bit to identify your JPA Entity `User` belongs not to Cassandra and so Spring Data Cassandra tries to create a Repository instance for your `UserRepository`.

You'll see some `DEBUG` log messages saying Spring Data is entering strict configuration mode if you enable `DEBUG` logging.

### Why comes this bug now and not with an earlier Spring Boot version?

Spring Boot 1.3.0 introduced an auto-configuration for Spring Data Cassandra repositories. Because of this change, Spring Boot performs a [scan for Spring Data Cassandra repositories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.java) like you configured it with `@EnableCassandraRepositories` only.

Only the combination of a default `EnableCassandraRepositories` using multiple Spring Data modules reveals this bug.

### So, what now?

Set `spring.data.cassandra.repositories.enabled=false` in your `application.properties` to disable the auto-configuration since you're using `@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages="com.sarvint.cassandra.domain")` yourself.

I created a bug report [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-257), so you can track the progress if you like.

Comment: If i add `spring.data.cassandra.repositories.enabled=false` in application.properties it says there is no constructor for Repository class which is related to spring data JPA

Comment: Great, so you got rid of the Cassandra issue. The JPA thing is next, so create a new post containing the other stack trace.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question with Cassandra and Neo4J. Not like in this, I initially don't have any neo4j repositories. But it gave me the same error as for cassandra. Then I set spring.data.neo4j.repositories.enabled=false and it started to work fine. Thanks @mp911de for this information. Looks like the same bug is there with spring neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to HikariCP 2.4.4.  It contains this fix:

`issue 495: implemented iterator() method on custom FastList to support Tomcat
           memory leak detection.`

Comment: This did fix the issue with FastList , HikariCp , but not the actual spring data module conflict ! Anyway thank you